# Стильный ListBoxItem в XAML

Tags: wpf, listview, style, design, usercontrol

Как реализовать красивый дизайн на примере ListBoxItem, который будет внутри ListView?
 
Я думаю, что здесь можно сделать Пользовательский Контрол и потом его динамически создавать с нужным цветом, текстом и так далее, но мне кажется что это очередной костыль :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужны [шаблоны данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) (`DataTemplate`). Суть их в описании того, как должен выглядеть элемент `ItemsControl`'а. Пример из [статьи](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_4.php):

```
<ListBox Name="lstCars" Margin="5">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" CornerRadius="4" Width="370">
                    <Grid Margin="3">
                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <RowDefinition/>
                              <RowDefinition/>
                         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                         <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding Path=ModelName, Converter={StaticResource StringUpperConverter}}"/>
                         <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ModelNumber}"/>
                    </Grid>
              </Border>
           </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Тут вы описываете, что каждый элемент должен иметь обводку (`Border`), а внутри него должны располагаться два текстовых поля. Поля привязаны к разным значениям вью модели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаблоны данных также можно выносить в ресурсы, а потом ссылаться на них из свойства `ItemTemplate`.

В случае, когда нужно отображать элементы для объектов (вью моделей) разных типов (как правило, имеющих общего родителя), используются селекторы шаблона данных (`DataTemplateSelector`). Они работают следующим образом:

- для каждого типа описывается свой шаблон данных
- пишется класс-селектор, реализующий логику выбора шаблона на основе
  контекста
- этот класс-селектор указывается в свойстве `ItemTemplateSelector`
  (или другом аналогичном)

---

Ваша вью модель может содержать всего два свойства: статус и сообщение. Тогда вам нужно будет описать шаблон данных, в котором вы нарисуете ваш дизайн, а картинку и цвета привяжете к свойству статуса с помощью конвертеров. Либо вы можете добавить свойства, содержащие соответствующую картинку и цвета, прямо во вью модель, и привязываться к ним из шаблона напрямую.

Comment: Это понятно а как вот сделать что-то типа промежутка или отступа между круглешком и прямоугольником ?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy судя по тому, что вы хотели динамически создавать контрол с заданными цвета, это для вас должно быть новым материалом :). Насчет промежутка: это можно делать совершенно разными способами. Это может быть, например, единая картинка (круг+прямоугольник) -- вариант очень логичный, учитывая, что содержимое и цвет круга жестко сцеплено с цветом прямоугольника. Это может быть, например, круглая кнопка с бордером вокруг.

Comment: а как сделать прозрачный border? Ну в смысле чтобы промежутка как бы не было. И ещё а есть ли какая нибудь информация по "а картинку и цвета привяжете к свойству статуса с помощью конвертеров", что нибудь вроде статей?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy про конвертеры можно почитать тут в разделе "Конвертеры значений": http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_1.php